# OS X kernel panic when attempting to access PCI memory-mapped register

Tags: macos, kernel, iokit, pci, kernel-extension

the code i'm referring to is [here](https://github.com/i3roly/CMI8788/blob/master/CMI8788/PCIAudioDevice.cpp#L165)

when i create a memory mapping for a pcidevice, i am always getting the same value for `getPhysicalAddress` and `getVirtualAddress`:
e.g.

> ```
> pciDevice = OSDynamicCast(IOPCIDevice, provider);
> deviceMap = pciDevice->mapDeviceMemoryWithRegister(kIOPCIConfigBaseAddress0);
>
> deviceRegisters = (struct oxygen *)  deviceMap->getVirtualAddress();
> pciDevice->setMemoryEnable(true);
> pciDevice->setBusMasterEnable(true);
> deviceMap->getPhysicalAddress();
> ```

now, actually, i’m not too surprised by this because i think this is the point of “DMA”.

- if we have some kind of mapping in the driver, then one is all we need.

  > - that is, the physicaladdress *is* the virtual address as it’s the sole spot we need to do the “memory to memory” (cpu datastore to PCI sound card)

is this understanding correct?

now for the main issue: i am experiencing kernel panics that are caused caused by any access or assignment of deviceRegisters’ members, such as:

```
kprintf("Xonar Vendor ID:0x%04x, Device ID:0x%04x, SubDevice ID:0x%04x, Physical Address:%lu\n",
       vendor_id, dev_id, subdev_id, deviceRegisters->addr);
```

now that tells me something i am doing something wrong in terms of allocation since accessing members of this structure should not cause a panic.

however if you look at listing 3-2 here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/WritingAudioDrivers/ImplementDriver/ImplementDriver.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000732-DontLinkElementID_15

this is exactly how it is supposed to be done.

a wise man (pmj) suggested i must use ioRead/Write functions to assign/access these values, but this does not really jive with the (admittedly old) skeleton code provided by apple. what could cause access issues to this memory mapping? surely having to do pointer arithmetic to assign/read values, while probably correct, is not the purpose of this design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i create a memory mapping for a pcidevice, i am always getting the same value for getPhysicalAddress and getVirtualAddress: e.g.

Are the values by any chance in the range `0x0..0xffff`?

I very strongly suspect this is a [port-mapped I/O range in your PCI device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space#Bus_enumeration), not a memory-mapped range.

The way to check for this in your code is:

```
if (0 != (kIOPCIIOSpace & pciDevice->configRead32(kIOPCIConfigBaseAddress0))
{
    // port mapped range
}
else
{
    // memory mapped range
}
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44352611/48660

> now, actually, i’m not too surprised by this because i think this is the point of “DMA”.

No, port-mapped I/O is pretty much the opposite of DMA. You can certainly use port-mapped I/O to initiate a DMA transfer if that's how your device happens to operate, so perhaps it'd be better phrased as being orthogonal to DMA.

DMA is about devices directly accessing system memory. PCI BARs are about the CPU accessing device registers or memory.

> if we have some kind of mapping in the driver, then one is all we need.
>   that is, the physicaladdress is the virtual address as it’s the sole spot we need to do the “memory to memory” (cpu datastore to PCI sound card)
>   is this understanding correct?

No, at least on x86, the I/O port address space is completely separate from the physical memory address space, and therefore also can't be mapped into virtual address space, as the MMU translates between virtual and physical *memory* spaces. On x86, there are special machine instructions, `in` and `out`, for reading and writing from I/O ports. On most architectures (for OS X notably PPC, but I think it's the case for ARM too), there is some form of memory mapping going on, however. I don't know how it works in detail on those architectures, but for the purposes of this question, you don't really need to care:

The architecture-independent way of performing I/O on a port-mapped range in a macOS kext is to use the `ioread*` and `iowrite*` methods on `IOPCIDevice`, where `*` can be `8`, `16`, or `32` for the 3 different possible I/O word sizes allowed by the PCI standard.

> now for the main issue: i am experiencing kernel panics that are caused caused by any access or assignment of deviceRegisters’ members, such as:

Assuming you are in fact dealing with a port-mapped I/O range in your device, then this explains your kernel panics. Use `pciDevice->ioread16(register_offset, deviceMap)` or similar.

> a wise man (pmj) suggested i must use ioRead/Write functions to assign/access these values, but this does not really jive with the (admittedly old) skeleton code provided by apple.

The document you linked to assumes the device's BAR is referring to a memory mapped range, not a port-mapped I/O range.